# Java Collections Interface Dynamic Dispatch

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, interface

```
Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0);
list.add(1);
list.add(2);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  list.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(list);
  }

}
```

My Question:
Why does the list uses remove(object o) rather than ArrayList.remove (int index).  I thought during compile time, list would what the actual object (dynamic type) (Arraylist's methods) not the superclass's methods.

Comment: This executes `remove(Object)` because your `list` variable is of type `Collection`, and `Collection` does not specify a `remove(int index)` method. The compiler is only looking at the compile-type of the variable (Collection), not the runtime-type of the object (ArrayList).

Comment: Don’t you notice the contradiction in your expectation (*compile time* and *dynamic type*) yourself? Letting the technical problems of using a dynamic (aka runtime) type at compile-time aside: What was the purpose of compile-time variable types when the programming language always used the runtime type instead?

Answer (score 2):

This executes [`remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) because your `list` variable is of type `Collection`, and `Collection` does not specify a `remove(int index)` method.

The compiler is only looking at the compile-time type of the variable (`Collection`), not the runtime type of the object (`ArrayList`).

Comment: So wait...because the static type is List. Because remove(int index) does not exist in list, so autobox happens so it calls remove(object) so the compiler looks remove(object) method in the ArrayList rather than remove(int index) version, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the static type is List". The compiler looks for a suitable method in `Collection`, and the only one it finds is `remove(Object)`. So it autoboxes the int to an Integer, yes. The `remove(int index)` method in `ArrayList` is not under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Since `list` is declared as `Collection<Integer>`, then the methods of `Collection` are called.

```java
Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
list.add(0);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  list.remove(i);
  System.out.println("after remove " + i + " -> " + list);
}
```

output:

```
after remove 0 -> [2, 1]
after remove 1 -> [2]
after remove 2 -> []
```

Also it'd error-prone to remove an element from the `ArrayList` by index and keep incrementing the index at the same time:

```java
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
list.add(0);

List<Integer> lst = (List<Integer>) list;
System.out.println(lst);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // size fixed
  lst.remove(i); // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 1
  System.out.println("after remove from list " + i + " -> " + lst);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is `Collection` and Collection does not have `remove(int index)` but has `remove(Object o)`, remove is `remove(Object o)`.

When you change Collection to `java.util.List` like below, remove works like `remove(int index)`.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0);
list.add(1);
list.add(2);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    list.remove(i); // IndexOutOfBoundsException expected though
}
System.out.println(list);
```